# ¿Por qué mi button no ejecuta mi función en mouseout?

Tags: javascript, html5, dom

Tengo el siguiente `button`:

```
<button type="button" id="myButton" onmouseover="myChange(this)" onmouseout="normalize(this)">Click me!</button>
```

Y la siguiente función cuando se retira el mouse del `button`:

```
function normalize(boton){
  boton.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  boton.style.color = "white";
  boton.style.border = "none";
}
```

Pues simplemente no se ejecuta, ¿a qué se debe?

Comment: Intenta cambiando el nombre de la función normalize,  pues esa función de javascript, que se encarga devolver un string Unicode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Al parecer tu función `normalize` está entrando en conflicto con [`String.prototype.normalize()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize).

Simplemente cámbiale el nombre a tu función:

```js
function myChange(boton) {
    boton.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    boton.style.color = "black";
    boton.style.border = "none";
}

function myNormalize(boton) {
    boton.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    boton.style.color = "white";
    boton.style.border = "none";
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="myButton" onmouseover="myChange(this)" onmouseout="myNormalize(this)">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: pfff si no se de la existencia de esa función jamas lo solucionaba gracias !

Comment: @CristoferFuentes de nada ;-)